# discord.py / Ошибка отправки элементов из массива

Tags: python, discord.py

Я открываю файл с диска, считываю его и полностью передаю в массив arr

После чего проверяю на количество элементов: если их меньше 20, то отправляю весь массив сразу.

Если их больше 20, то "разделяю" его на две части и отправляю на канал обе части отдельно.

В случае, если элементов меньше 20, все работает четко и как надо. Отправляются все элементы в нужном мне порядке.

Но если элементов больше, отправляется всего по 1 элементу массива.

Принтил массив, прежде чем вывести - все на месте, но в дискорд отправляется какая-то корявость.

```
with open("local.txt", "r") as onfile:
    
    arr = onfile.readlines()
    arrlen = len(arr)
    
    if arrlen < 20:   
        full_data = ''.join(arr)
        await channel.send(full_data)
        print('STEP 1')
        
    elif arrlen > 19:
        
        i = 0
        while i < 19:
            full_data1 = ''.join(arr[i])
            i += 1
        
        
        await channel.send(full_data1)
        
        
        i = 20
        while i < arrlen:
            full_data2 = ''.join(arr[i])
            i += 1
        
        
        await channel.send(full_data2)
        
        
        print('STEP 2')
```

Для примера: если строк в файле меньше 20, то все идет и отправляется как и записано в файле:

Строчка1
Строчка2
Строчка3
Строчка4
Строчка5
и т.д

Если больше, то получается что-то в духе:
одно сообщешие: Строчка2
второе сообщение: Строчка6

Comment: Понял причину проблемы. Я по сути просто перезаписываю full_data# на последний элемент arr[i], поэтому на выводе получается криво.
Подскажите, как записать правильно в него, чтобы вписались правильно нужные мне строчки в нужные массивы, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно отправлять содержимое файла так, чтобы одно сообщение содержало максимум 20 строк

В вашу реализацию я особо не вникал, потому что уж очень сложно вы пытаетесь это сделать.

---

**На самом деле можно сделать так:**

Считываем строки файла в список:

```py
with open("local.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Затем отправляем в канал первые 20 строк

```py
await channel.send(''.join(lines[:20]))
```

После чего отрезаем только что отправленные элементы от списка

```py
lines = lines[20:]
```

В какой-то момент вы обрежете последние элементы списка и он станет пустым. В этот момент нужно прекратить отправлять данные. Эту проверку можно реализовать с помощью цикла `while len(lines) > 0`

Чтобы понять как работает обрезание списков, рекомендую почитать про [**срезы в Python**](https://proproprogs.ru/python_base/spiski-srezy-i-metody)

Полный код:

```py
with open("local.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

while len(lines) > 0:
    await channel.send(''.join(lines[:20]))
    lines = lines[20:]
```

Comment: Спасибо, буквально за две минуты до поста этого смог разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Додумался.

```
with open("local.txt", "r") as onfile:
    
    arr = onfile.readlines()
    arrlen = len(arr)
    
    if arrlen < 20:   
        full_data = ''.join(arr)
        await channel.send(full_data)
        print('STEP 1')
        
    elif arrlen > 19:

        full_data1 = ''.join(arr[0:19])
        await channel.send(full_data1)
           
        full_data2 = ''.join(arr[20:arrlen])
        await channel.send(full_data2)
```